# "targetContentOffset" UICollectionViewFlowLayout not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a requirement to keep UICollectionViewCell center aligned in portrait mode.
Final result should be like :
[animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzo2cowb9ny5l1l/Video%20Aug%2010%2C%2011%2058%2011%20PM.m4v?dl=0)

I'm using this code to do this:

```
override public func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

var layoutAttributes: Array = layoutAttributesForElements(in: collectionView!.bounds)!

if layoutAttributes.count == 0 {
    return proposedContentOffset
}

var firstAttribute: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = layoutAttributes[0]

for attribute: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in layoutAttributes {
    if attribute.representedElementCategory != .cell {
        continue
    }

    if((velocity.x >= 0.0 && attribute.center.x > firstAttribute.center.x) ||
        (velocity.x <= 0.0 && attribute.center.x < firstAttribute.center.x)) {
        firstAttribute = attribute;
    }
}

return CGPoint(x: firstAttribute.center.x - 

collectionView!.bounds.size.width * 0.5, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
}
```

This works fine for all cell except the last cell which doesn't get center aligned  upon scrolling.

Actual result:

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @PGDev updated question with the link

Comment: What happen on the last cell?

Comment: That last cell doesn’t get Center aligned,it behaves just like normal scrolling.

Comment: @Larme updated question with screenshot.

Comment: Try giving sectionInsets of the collectionView

Comment: I have given sectionInset (0,16,0,16) @PGDev

Comment: Your animation link is not working..can you please check.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzo2cowb9ny5l1l/Video%20Aug%2010%2C%2011%2058%2011%20PM.m4v?dl=0

Comment: @PGDev this is the link,please check if you are able to see the animation.

Comment: @Arun_ check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the `UICollectionViewCell` in center, you need to change the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` of `UICollectionView`,i.e. make subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and set it as `UICollectionView's` Layout in `storyboard`.

**1. `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass**

```
class CollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
    {
        if let collectionViewBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds
        {
            let halfWidthOfVC = collectionViewBounds.size.width * 0.5
            let proposedContentOffsetCenterX = proposedContentOffset.x + halfWidthOfVC
            if let attributesForVisibleCells = self.layoutAttributesForElements(in: collectionViewBounds)
            {
                var candidateAttribute : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
                for attributes in attributesForVisibleCells
                {
                    let candAttr : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? = candidateAttribute
                    if candAttr != nil
                    {
                        let a = attributes.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX
                        let b = candAttr!.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX
                        if fabs(a) < fabs(b)
                        {
                            candidateAttribute = attributes
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        candidateAttribute = attributes
                        continue
                    }
                }

                if candidateAttribute != nil
                {
                    return CGPoint(x: candidateAttribute!.center.x - halfWidthOfVC, y: proposedContentOffset.y);
                }
            }
        }
        return CGPoint.zero
    }
}
```

**2. `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width - (2 * kCellSpacing) - (2 * kCellInset), height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    return cellSize
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return kCellSpacing
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    let sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, kCellSpacing + kCellInset, 0, kCellSpacing + kCellInset)
    return sectionInset
}
```

Check the above code and let me know if this satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Works perfectly..Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure..Happy coding..:)

Comment: this was working but only if you do as @mmk mentions bellow that `collectionView.isPagingEnabled` must be false

Answer (score 5):

I found that if I set

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

it will broken the center cell setting. Once I turn it off, everything works fine again

Answer (score 0):

For subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView
        else { return .zero }
    let horizontalcenter = proposedContentOffset.x + collectionView.bounds.width / 2.0

    let proposedRect = CGRect(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: proposedContentOffset.y, width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    var offsetAdjusment = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    if let layoutAttributes = layoutAttributesForElements(in: proposedRect){

        for attributes in layoutAttributes{
            if attributes.representedElementCategory != UICollectionElementCategory.cell{
                continue
            }

            let itemHorizontalCenter = attributes.center.x
            if abs(itemHorizontalCenter - horizontalcenter) < abs(offsetAdjusment){
                offsetAdjusment = itemHorizontalCenter - horizontalcenter
            }
        }
    }

    return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjusment, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
}
```