# Move CollectionViewCell to another section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, sections

I have a UIViewController with a collectionView inside it.  The layout may seem confusing but I am making use of horizontal scrolling UICollectionViewCells, presented in 3 sections.
The main collection view is made up of 3 sections.  I access 3 different UICollectionViewCell classes for each section becuase it is fetching different data for each one.  Once the data is fetched, it dequeues another Cell class, which is the same one accessed for all the sections.

There are 2 buttons in each cell.  When I press the button, a value changes within the database.  When I re-run the program, the cell in which the button was pressed has moved to its corresponding section that it should be in as per the change.  However, I want to achieve this as soon as I press the button.  How can I move the cell from one section to another, baring in mind that they the cells presented are inside a collectionview cell making up the sections, which is then inside a greater UICollectionView.?
I've tried researching how to do this but no luck, and everyone seems to be using a drag and drop method which seems too complicated for what I am trying to achieve.  Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the structure of your data source. Basically 1) remove the item at given index path from the source section array and keep it temporarily. 2) Insert the item at desired index into the destination section array. 3) call `collectionView.beginUpdates()`. 4) call `collectionView.deleteRows...` passing the source index path. 5) call `collectionView.insertRows...` passing the destination index path. 6) call `collectionView.endUpdates()`.

Comment: Yes, this logic seems to be the correct method, however the trouble I am having is figuring out how to move the item between sections as each section of the collectionView further has its own UICollectionViewCell class...

Comment: For example; collectionView that has 3 sections. Then in the cellForItem a UICollectionViewCell depending on the section.
`if indexPath.section == 0 {
dequeue AnimalsILikeCollectionViewCellsHolder()
else if indexPath.section == 1 {
dequeue AnimalsIHateCollectionViewCellsHolder()
}` etc...
Then within each of these two CellHolders, I dequeue an AnimalsCollectionViewCell that allows the pictures to appear and a like and dislike button.
When I click the dislike button, I want the cell to remove itself from the likeSection to the dislikeSection. 
If this makes sense i'd appreciate any help

Comment: @Dee, did you get a solution for your particular implementation?

Comment: Hey @ImrulKayes - I have found part of the solution.  I have been racking my brain way too long now and trying different implementations.  What I managed to do was call back from my cell that has the button, and when pressed it calls back to the cell it has been dequeued from.. it then removes the item from array and then reloads the section via a batchUpdate.  This removes the cell from the collectionviewcell it is in, however once it has been removed... now I need to add that cell to the OTHER collectionview that is in another section of the parent collectionview but having trouble doing it

Comment: @Dee, you might have solved your problem. I was trying to implement your idea a little bit. [Here is my github repo](https://github.com/kayes55/ProjectDee) of the project I have done so far. Please check if that may help. And I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some feedback on this project.

Comment: @ImrulKayes - Wow, I really appreciate you taking the time to help and recreating the problem.  I implemented delegation as you did and it worked perfectly.. I was using callbacks before but delegates work a lot better.  I had to adjust as per the object I am receiving from my database, and it gave me exactly the result I was looking for.  Thank you soo much again!!! :)

Comment: @Dee, I am glad that it helped. Do you mind if I repost my previous comment with that project repository as an Answer so that it might help others? And would you please mark that as an accepted answer?

Comment: @ImrulKayes, Of course! Great answer, you deserve some credit for it- could help others :)

Comment: @ImrulKayes,  At the moment the scrolling is smooth, I enabled paging to get a paging effect when sliding across, however the cell that should be in the middle is not centered at the middle of the page? Have you come across this?

Comment: @Dee I didn't face that problem. I was using static data and you probably using some kind of API to fetch data. If you can provide some code then I would try to resolve that.

Comment: @ImrulKayes - Dont worry, it's not a data issue but a UI one.   Managed to figure it out.  Had to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and do some adjustments.  This is the link I followed incase you're interested- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614617/targetcontentoffset-uicollectionviewflowlayout-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I followed to achieve the above situation is using a **custom Delegation** when cell is removing from collectionviews. A container CollectionView has two sections with 2 different cells containing two different **Horizontal UICollectionViews**. These two collectionview's cells have UIButtons. When tap on one collectionView's button, that particular cell is removed, custom Delegate method calls and another CollectionView's cell is populated. [This is the link of the project](https://github.com/kayes55/ProjectDee) I have created for this particular scenario. For better understanding, here is a ***GIF*** for demonstration.

[image: Demonstrated GIF]